# Read hive table avro data from Presto

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, presto

Following is my query in presto

```
select* from hive.default.presto_logoperation_table;
```

But I am getting the following :

> Query 20151005_130248_00028_guis8 failed: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.SchemaResolutionProblem

can anyone tell where am i missing ?

Comment: can you tell which Presto version are you running? What's your table definition looks like?